# Issue in converting the date format using NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

All,

In My project i want to convert date from MM-dd-yyyy to M/d/YY (12/31/15) but i am getting wrong format, below is the code i am using.

```
-(NSString*)dateConversionForWarranty:(NSString *)string
{
```

string  i am getting as 12-31-2014

```
    NSDateFormatter* df_utc = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df_utc setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];

    NSDate *date = [df_utc dateFromString:string];
```

When i am converting it i am getting date as this "2014-12-30 18:30:00 +0000"

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"M/d/YY"];
```

Then when i try to convert to above format i am getting the year completely wrong "12/31/15"

```
    NSString *formattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    return formattedDate;

}
```

Can any one tell me where i am wrong

Comment: What you'r trying to achieve..?

Comment: I want date in "12/31/15" in this format for the date i am getting in "MM-dd-yyyy" format, I want to convert the format

Comment: "12/31/15" *is* the YY format that you asked for.  But generally, no one really intends to use that format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use capital "Y" -- it produces a very unpredictable value for dates near the start/end of the year ([look it up](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)). You can use a single "M" if you wish, to suppress leading zeros in the month.

In summary:

- d - day of month
- M - month
- y - year
- h - hour -- 12 hour clock
- H - hour -- 24 hour clock
- m - minute
- s - second
- S - fraction of a second
- a - AM/PM

The number of repeats corresponds to the field width (though not always 1:1).  Eg "MMMM" will give you the full-length spelled-out month name, while "MMM" gives the 3-letter abbreviation and "MM" gives the 2-digit numeric month.  Refer to the spec (highlighted above) for details.

Answer (score 0):

> i want date in this format 12/31/15 then which type of formatter

try this `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];`.

For more info about the [Date Formatting patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: Okk, If i want date in this format 12/31/15 then which type of formatter we need to use

Answer (score -1):

Do it in below way..

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];
// or 

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm"];
```

Comment: D :- for date M :- Month and Y:- year